# Firebase Firestore, how to handle events when offline and then connect online?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore has events listeners for OnComplete, OnSuccess and OnFailure.

Those events are triggered when online only.

When the mobile phone is offline,  those events are not triggered until the phone is back online.

But let's say I have 3 different activities that I can add data.
While I am offline I can add data many times on many activities.

How should I handle this ?
If I want the user to be able to add data offline,  then should I ignore the events and don't add listeners ?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear about the situation you're envisioning.  Could you be more clear about what problem are you trying to address (spell it out step by step)?

Comment: if the user is offline, what is the point of the OnComplete event, if he can use the app totally offline?       Remember that the OnCompete event doesn't get called when the user is offline.

Comment: The point of the callbacks is to be notified of a change as soon as it happens, and you don't have to track the online/offline state of the app yourself to get those changes.

Comment: Firestore queries/listeners (e.g. `onSnapshot`) fire for local data changes immediately, so that you can update your UI. But **completion** listeners (such as  `onComplete`, `onSuccess` and `onFailure`), only fire once the data is committed to (or rejected by) the server. What listeners are you talking about?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen,  I am talking about onComplete, onSuccess and onFailure, when adding data to Firestore.

Comment: OK. So those only fire when the data is committed or rejected on the server. What are you trying to accomplish with these listeners? Some code would probably help understand more whatyou're trying to accomplish.

Comment: So if the app should work offline,  should I ignore the listeners and just let the user add data? The app could be closed and opened  at a later time and the data will be committed later when online.

Comment: What if I need to know when the offline data is synced with the server )(when the user is online again)? I need to know this because as soon as the data is synchronized, I need to do update some fields in the server.